# Knockout autocomplete with jquery doesn't allow to select custom value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete

I've read [this topic](http://cameron-verhelst.be/blog/2014/04/20/knockoutjs-autocomplete/) how to implement autocomplete with knockout.

I've made it to work, but notice that I couldn't select my own-typed value.

---

More description: I type any string into input that doesn't exists in autocomplete source. As result this string isn't setted as value of that input.

---

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
    // Only using init event because the Jquery.UI.AutoComplete widget will take care of the update callbacks
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // { selected: mySelectedOptionObservable, options: myArrayOfLabelValuePairs }
        var settings = valueAccessor();

        var selectedOption = settings.selected;
        var options = settings.options;
        var elVal = $(element).val();

        var updateElementValueWithLabel = function (event, ui) {
            // Stop the default behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            // Update the value of the html element with the label 
            // of the activated option in the list (ui.item)
            $(element).val(ui.item !== null ? ui.item.label : elVal);

            // Update our SelectedOption observable
            if(typeof ui.item !== "undefined") {
                // ui.item - label|value|...
                selectedOption(ui.item);
            }
        };

        $(element).autocomplete({
            source: options,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
            }
        });
    }
};

// Array with original data
var remoteData = [{
    name: 'Ernie',
    id: 1
}, {
    name: 'Bert',
    id: 2
}, {
    name: 'Germaine',
    id: 3
}, {
    name: 'Sally',
    id: 4
}, {
    name: 'Daisy',
    id: 5
}, {
    name: 'Peaches',
    id: 6
}];

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.users = remoteData;
    
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable('');
    self.options = self.users.map(function (element) {
        // JQuery.UI.AutoComplete expects label & value properties, but we can add our own
        return {
            label: element.name,
            value: element.id,
            // This way we still have acess to the original object
            object: element
        };
    });
}

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete/master/build/knockout-jqAutocomplete.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="autoComplete: { selected: selectedOption, options: options }" />

<!-- Debugging -->
<p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedOption())"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the binding to accept values that aren't in the options list you'll need to adjust `updateElementValueWithLabel` to not reset the element value when an item isn't selected.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
    // Only using init event because the Jquery.UI.AutoComplete widget will take care of the update callbacks
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // { selected: mySelectedOptionObservable, options: myArrayOfLabelValuePairs }
        var settings = valueAccessor();

        var selectedOption = settings.selected;
        var options = settings.options;
        var elVal = $(element).val();

        var updateElementValueWithLabel = function (event, ui) {
            // Stop the default behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            // Update our SelectedOption observable
            if(ui.item) {
                // Update the value of the html element with the label 
                // of the activated option in the list (ui.item)
                // ui.item - label|value|...
                $(element).val(ui.item.label);
                selectedOption(ui.item.label);
            }else{
              selectedOption($(element).val());
            }
        };

        $(element).autocomplete({
            source: options,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
            }
        });
    }
};

// Array with original data
var remoteData = [{
    name: 'Ernie',
    id: 1
}, {
    name: 'Bert',
    id: 2
}, {
    name: 'Germaine',
    id: 3
}, {
    name: 'Sally',
    id: 4
}, {
    name: 'Daisy',
    id: 5
}, {
    name: 'Peaches',
    id: 6
}];

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.users = remoteData;
    
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable('');
    self.options = self.users.map(function (element) {
        // JQuery.UI.AutoComplete expects label & value properties, but we can add our own
        return {
            label: element.name,
            value: element.id,
            // This way we still have acess to the original object
            object: element
        };
    });
}

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete/master/build/knockout-jqAutocomplete.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="autoComplete: { selected: selectedOption, options: options }" />

<!-- Debugging -->
<p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedOption())"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I am trying to do